# How to suppress PowerShell Get-Content output

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script:

script.ps1

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $Config;

function Get-ScriptDirectory
{
    Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
}

function Load-Config
{
    $configPath = Join-Path (Get-ScriptDirectory) config.xml
    $global:Config = [xml](gc $configPath) 
}

Load-Config
```

config.xml

```
<Configuration>
</Configuration>
```

Later in the script I'm working with $Config variable. When I run this script it writes the output to the console, which contains the root element of the xml. Something like:

```
Configuration
--------------
```

Is there exists any way how to suppress this output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the output isn't caused by the assignment statement (a voidable statement), but by this line:

`[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $Config;`

In PowerShell, typically, all statements return a value (except for voidable statements).  I think that the first time you run the script no output will be written to the console. However on subsequent runs `$Config` will still contain the value of the previous run, and its value will be written to the screen.

- piping to the Out-Null cmdlet:
  `[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $Config | Out-Null`
- casting to void:
  `[void][System.Xml.XmlDocument]$Config`
- assigning to $null:
  `$null = $Config`
- or simply not 'declaring' the `$Config` variable

are ways to suppress this behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want the output of a command to be printed out to the console, you can **discard it** by *piping* it or *redirecting* it to [Out-Null](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315279.aspx). For example both will work:

```
$Config | Out-Null
$Config > Out-Null
```

If you're familiar with Unix-like operating systems, [Out-Null](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315279.aspx) is *conceptually* equivalent to `/dev/null`.

Comment: You can also assign to `$null`. In any case, it's not actually the same, as you *redirect* do `/dev/null` but *pipe* to `Out-Null`.

Comment: @Joey Correct, since `/dev/null` is represented as a file. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I have updated my question to better describe my code. I have tried your advises, but it doesn't helped me. Because when I redirect the output, my Config variable is empty in the next function when I'm calling it.

Comment: @zosim The code in the `Load-Config` function shouldn't print anything to the console. Could you please post the entire script?

Comment: I have updated question. It is just a fragment, but it is enough to see the behaviour I'm describing.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you're dumping the variable from your script. As it falls out of the pipe it gets passed to Out-Host and that will yield the output you see.

The actual solution is to make sure you don't return anything from your script. As I cannot see your code I can't point to where, but somewhere there is a pipeline or statement that leaks the object into output. Are you sure you're using an assignment at every place you need?

Answer (score 0):

A few Options:

```
# Pipe to the Out-Null cmdlet
$Config | Out-Null

# Cast to void
[void]$Config 

# assign to $null
$null = $Config

# redirect to $null
$Config > $null
```