# Don't show feedback from Add-SPSolution

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a script in which I add a solution and then install it. The script runs fine and the solution is added and deployed, and it looks like this:

```
param([string]$LiteralPath)

if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($LiteralPath)){
    Write-Error "ERROR: Please include the path to the WSP file"
    return
}

Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath $LiteralPath -Confirm:$false
Install-SPSolution -Identity {GUID} -GACDeployment -AllWebApplications
Write-Host "Solution added and deployed"
```

However because the `Add-SPSolution` command outputs right after it finishes, I get the following output:

```
Name                           SolutionId                           Deployed
----                           ----------                           --------
{SOLUTION NAME}                {GUID}                               False
Solution added and deployed
```

Although there's a 2nd line saying the solution is deployed, I want to disable the output from `Add-SPSolution` to not induce the user in error. How can I do it?

**EDIT** I was unaware that we could store the output from `Add-SPSolution` in a variable, which the OP from [the supposed duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881174/redirecting-output-to-null-in-powershell-but-ensuring-the-variable-remains-set) was aware of, so I don't think my question classifies as duplicate.

Comment: Try [the](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18782528/5806659)[se](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8985313/5806659).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting output to $null in PowerShell, but ensuring the variable remains set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881174/redirecting-output-to-null-in-powershell-but-ensuring-the-variable-remains-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign this to a variable, PowerShell won't output / return the result directly in your console.

Example:

```
$solution = Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath $LiteralPath -Confirm:$false
$install = Install-SPSolution -Identity {GUID} -GACDeployment -AllWebApplications;
```

The return of the cmdlets will then be assigned to your variables where you can access them later if you need it.

Comment: It works, thanks! By the way, where can I find the API for the object that is returned into the `$solution` variable? I would like to see the description for the methods I have access to.

Comment: It's the SPSolution object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsolution.aspx). You can at any time pipe the object to the Get-member cmdlet too see what variables and functions are available on the object, if you don't want to look up the API or can't find a the api. Example: $solution | Get-Member

Answer (score 3):

The best method would be to use Out-Null which will load the solution but delete the unnecessary output. The desired syntax will be:

> Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath $LiteralPath -Confirm:$false | Out-Null